# Which is better foreign key user or profile

Tags: mysql, database

Just asking which is better to this simple question

the foreign key is on the `user_profiles`

```
[users]
id
username
email
password
first_name
last_name
....


[user_profiles]
id
user_id --
hobby
school
contact
work
...
```

or on the `users`

```
[users]
id
user_profile_id --
username
email
password
first_name
last_name
....


[user_profiles]
id
hobby
school
contact
work
...
```

Comment: Which is considered to be the 'parent' table? Put another way, can you have multiple user profiles for a single user, or can you have multiple users for a single user profile? If it's a one-to-one relationship why do you have multiple tables?

Comment: It depends wich entity is your main entity, its' a logical question.

Comment: @BobJarvis cause having too many column is not too good?

Comment: @SylvainMARTIN what do you mean about that sir? I'm still newbie on the SQL

Comment: Your choice will determine wich entity depends the other one, this relation is important, it will determine how you want to determine the relashionship beetween a user and its profil information. It is a choice you must take in consideration to build thegraphical interface of you application if needed.

Comment: Generally ist option is good becuase u cant do anything until unless u have login credentials

Comment: What do you mean by "having too many column is not too good"? IMO creating additional 1-to-1 tables in order to reduce the number of columns in any one table adds complexity and reduces performance without any appreciable benefit. YMMV. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The former: user_profiles belongs to user.
The latter: user belongs to user_profiles.

So, the former may be more sensable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in case that every user should have a profile, I think that you have to implement the second choice. it's the logic choice, because each user should have a profile (the column id_profil never will be empty).
if you implement the first choice how you will treat the case where a profile has a lot of users.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding **Point 1** is better than to other one. Why?

- in **Point 1** your primary table is user and you must need to store initial information first like username and password.
- after storing initial information you can store secondary information for suppose if a person who didn't want to post thier hobbies and school information but atleast want an account **Point 1** is the better option for him.
- some people want to save multiple hobbies and school acadmic information in this scenario **Point 1** always the best option for one to many relation.
- if you chose **Point 2** and hobbies and academic information more than 1 than you must need multiple rows in user table.

**Side note:**

I know its not enough points but it just a little summary and it just my suggestion you can implement as per your requirements.